# Is there a way to see old /var after mounting to a new partition?

Tags: mount

After moving var to a new partition by the following commands, How can I see the old var ?

```
mkdir /var2
mount /dev/sda5 /var2
```

Sync your current var:

```
rsync -a /var/ /var2
```

Add the entry to /etc/fstab

```
/dev/sda5    /var    ext4    defaults      2 2
```

Comment: only way: rename old var directory before restart init5 mode

Comment: I could mark it as answer and properly close the question if you can make an answer @cmak.fr

Comment: answer is posted

Answer (score 0):

Moving the `/var` directory to a new separate disk or partition and keep access to the old `/var` directory.
To 'see' an old var directory after fstab modificaton : rename the old var directory.

```
# Boot with init 1 single user mode
sudo init 1

# Prepare new VAR directory
mkdir /mnt/newvar
mount /dev/sda5 /mnt/newvar
cp -ax /var/* /mnt/newvar

# Rename old VAR
mv /var /old_var
# Remount the disk partition to /var
mkdir /var
umount /dev/sda5
mount /dev/sda5 /var

# Alter fstab to apply changes
#--> /dev/sda5    /var    ext4    defaults    0    2

# Restart the multitask mode
init 5
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the new partition mounted on `/var` already, you can use a bind-mount:

```
sudo mount --bind / /mnt
```

This will mount your root-partition at `/mnt` without affecting the current mount-points, so when looking in `/mnt`, you will see the original directory contents.

Thus you will find the content of your `"old" /var` in `/mnt/var` now. If you want to remove the content of your `"old" /var` you can use

```
sudo rm -r /mnt/var/*
```

Unmount when your done with

```
sudo umount /mnt
```

Comment: so when you have `/` you can (double) mount your `/' onto `/mnt' for the second time?

Comment: yes, sure, just try it out, it works.

Comment: Please see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1161537/how-to-remove-files-hidden-under-tmp-mountpoint , a similar question. This solution is the elegant way.