# ls files in directory where a mount is above it

Tags: mount, filesystem, nfs

Not sure on how to phrase the question easily.

I have a directory `/mnt/bla` in it MAYBE I have many files and directories.

On top of that directory, I mounted some nfs mount.

Is there a way to check if there are files in the directory underlying the mount without unmounting it?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4426/access-to-original-contents-of-mount-point

Comment: [This question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1165589/590937) is very similar to yours and my [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1166631/590937) will work for you, of course, you have to adapt the name of the mountpoint to `/mnt/bla` in the bind mount command.

Comment: @mook765 Please expand your comment to a full answer using the correct directory names from OP's case. I found it slightly confusing to read your original answer while mapping it on OP's problem :-)

Comment: @Jos You're right, it's a bit confusing, also another mountpoint than `/mnt` needs to be used since a filesystem is mounted to a subdirectory of `/mnt`. Asnwer is ready.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do so using a bind-mount. First you need to create a directory which we use as mount point for the bind-mount:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/mymountpoint
```

(We cannot use `/mnt` here as suggested in the links in the comments since you have a filesystem mounted on `/mnt/bla`)

Next step:

```
sudo mount --bind / /mnt/mymountpoint
```

Browse to `/mnt/mymountpoint/mnt/bla` to see what's in the folder. What you see here is the content of `/mnt/bla` as if nothing were mounted to it.

Move the content of `/mnt/mymountpoint/mnt/bla` to the location you want or remove the content completely.

Unmount the bind-mount with

```
sudo umount /mnt/mymountpoint
```

and remove the mountpoint with

```
sudo rmdir /mnt/mymountpoint
```

That's it.